# Storing Fuel Canisters with Stove Pump Attached

Tags: fuel

## The Question

1. Can I store my white gas fuel canister with the stove pump attached?

### Follow-up Questions

1. Is it safe to store white gas fuel canisters partially filled with white gas?
2. Does this hold true for other liquid gases?

Comment: Re: 1.1: Can you? Yes, you can. Should you? Depends... I don't own the original lids to my personal stove bottles -- all pump, all the time without a single leak. However, I NEVER allow participants on my guided trips to carry them with the pump attached (too many leaks).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would under no circumstances store your white gas stove that way.  White gas is pretty volatile stuff and the increased chance of a leak is just not worth it.  In addition, why?  I am not sure what benefit this would provide.

Yes, it is safe to store partially filled white gas canisters.  I would not leave them in direct sunlight with hot temperatures outside, but otherwise I have stored white gas for years in the shade, even in 90F ++ weather.  That being said, you should in some way mark where you are storing flammable gases so that no one goes out by your can and lights a cigarette.  If it is very hot, and your can is near empty, you **may** consider leaving the cap loose enough to relieve any pressure, but only do so in a very well ventilated area.

White gas is one of the more volatile liquid gases available to the general public.  Alcohol, kerosene, etc. are as-a-general-rule less likely to go boom from any given incident.  So I would say this hold true for other gases you are likely to be using.